# How can I change the style of a property dialog in LibGDX using JSON?

Tags: json, libgdx

In my `libGdx` project, I'm using a `.json` file to set the button style for the property dialog. I have two buttons: **red** (OFF) and **green** (ON).

I would like to toggle between them. Is there a way to style this in the `JSON` file?

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
   default: { down: ON_Button, up: ON_Button, font: default-font, fontColor: white },
   toggle: { down: ON_Button, up: ON_Button, checked: OFF_Button, font: default-font, fontColor: white, downFontColor: red }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons support `setChecked` method, so you could do this in one style:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    toggle: { 
        down: OFF_Button, // <- pressed
        up: OFF_Button, // <- not checked
        checked: ON_BUTTON, // <- checked
        font: default-font, 
        fontColor: white 
    },
},
```

And call `setChecked(bool)` method of your button to switch states. Furthermore, the button automatically switch checked state when you click it.

Comment: shouldn't this be the toggle instead of default? I don't really know much about JSON and this styles but as much as i understood the style he is looking for should be called toggle (it is no technical things just naming). And his JSON file is correct right?

Comment: @Springrbua, yes, this style should be named `checkbox` or `toggle` or something like this. Also, `TextButtonStyle` requires only `font` field as mandatory, so, yes, looks like correct.

Comment: Thank you. Until now i did not need this in my game, cause i have no menu but when i implement menu this info will help hopefully :P Thanks. +1

Comment: I can't get it to work. If I call `setChecked` on the button, doesn't it always show the on button? Could you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is to correctly define json. `setChecked` behavior is like `checkbox` and it have 2 states: not checked (default `up` field image) and checked (the `checked` image). Also please note, if you trying to implement checkbox, you shouldn't call `setChecked` manually, because `TextButton` will call this metod automatically after click.